# Ubuntu 20.04 Login loop after lots of updates

Tags: gnome, 20.04, login

I can get to the login screen, and try to login, but then it just flashes and takes me right back.

I've uninstalled my Nvidia drivers since that was one of the things that got updated. And I tried to disable my gnome extensions since I have a login background one, but `gnome-extensions list` doesn't show any. I had also re-`chow`ed my user directory recursively, so there's now ownership issues.

`journalctl cat -f -o /usr/bin/gnome-shell` returns just

```
gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Will monitor session ci
Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Not starting gsd-xsettings; waiting for gnome-session to do so
Regersring session with gdm
warning: failed to start gsd-xsettings
JS WARNING: [resource: ///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js 24]: reference to undefined property "MetaWindowXwayland"
```

and the output doesn't seem to get added to at all if I try going back to graphical and logging in again while journalctl is running.

So, unique from other instances of this issue on askubuntu, this has nothing to do with Nvidia drivers (since they were removed), doesn't produce any errors in Gnome itself, and isn't caused by user directory ownership/permissions issues.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question due to low quality, not really helpful for others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case... It was because I accidentally sourced my `.profile` from my `.bashrc`, when my `.profile` also sources my `.bashrc` creating a loop for any bash shell.
Bit of a face palm, but I guess the lesson it to start with the simplest stuff first.

So the part that is not mentioned in any questions here is that a malformed `.profile` or `.bashrc` can stop Gnome from loading, without throwing any errors to Gnome itself, causing a unique login loop.